# Please make the "buttons" in SE/sites' grid view middle-clickable!

Tags: feature-request, design, stackexchange.com

Twice now, I've gone to https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid, explored the grid as I middle-clicked things that looked interesting, then moved my eyes up to the tab-bar to discover that I wasn't clicking `<a>` elements, but **checks**—ah, `<div>`s with attached JavaScript.

I realize the current model expects that users will click the bubble, get some information, then visit the site, but some people use a "click-in-advance" browsing model, if you will. Personally, I find the need to click two elements to open the site annoying and extremely distracting.

As such, I have no idea if this would be possible (or how easy it would be), but it'd be cool if the buttons were middle-clickable *and* displayed more info on left-click. I expect this would probably be accomplished via a curious menagerie of `<a>` and `PreventDefault` (I *think*), but if done right, it'd let browsers like `Lynx`/`links`/`Dillo` work properly with the page (and I personally use `Dillo` a lot myself, I might add), and it'd also mean mobile browsers would properly popup an "open in new tab" menu on long-press.

Comment: Well, at least the "Visit site" button is middle-clickable. :)

Comment: True... that's what I've been using :P but clicking the grid elements can be sooo distracting... heh. I just discovered the "list" view mode though, which does provide middle-clickable links.